# Table is mutating error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote the following query to update the amount column in work_order_coding_tab from the values fetched by  work_order_coding view.

```
merge into work_order_coding_tab A
using work_order_coding B
on (A.WO_NO = B.WO_NO AND A.ROW_NO=B.ROW_NO)
when matched then update set A.amount = B.sales_price_amount
where
      A.WO_NO = B.WO_NO AND
      A.ROW_NO=B.ROW_NO  
      AND B.work_order_cost_type_db = 'M'
           AND B.order_no IS NULL
           AND B.catalog_no IS NOT NULL        
AND A.amount is not null and A.amount <> B.sales_price_amount and B.contract like 'TZ%'  
and abc.active_separate_api.get_line_no(B.wo_no) =2
AND A.WO_NO=2002 AND A.ROW_NO=3921;
```

But I'm getting the error, ora-04091 table is mutating, figure or function may not see it. I wrote the above query instead of following , as oracle doesn't support this.

```
UPDATE 
from
    work_order_coding_tab A
inner join work_order_coding B
on A.WO_NO = B.WO_NO AND A.ROW_NO=B.ROW_NO  
where
A.WO_NO = B.WO_NO AND
A.ROW_NO=B.ROW_NO  
AND B.work_order_cost_type_db = 'M'
     AND B.order_no IS NULL
     AND B.catalog_no IS NOT NULL        
     AND A.amount is not null and A.amount <> B.sales_price_amount and B.contract like 'TZ%'  
     and abc.active_separate_api.get_line_no(B.wo_no) =2;
```

Can any on please help me to identify the issue of this.

Comment: Make the `work_order_coding_tab.amount` column virtual and make it use a stored function, which will update it, based on the value of `work_order_coding.sales_price_amount`.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a trigger on the work_order_coding_tab table, and the trigger is trying to select from the same table. Perhaps you could edit your question to include the trigger, to allow us to see what's going on.

Comment: Will there be a be another way that I can use to update the same table. Writing the query in another way

Comment: The issue lies with the trigger, not your statement, IMHO.